# Change vlc media_player process name

Tags: python, pyinstaller, vlc, libvlc

Is it possible to change the display name of the python-vlc module in the volume window?

I'm using this sample code

```
import vlc
inst = vlc.Instance()
player = inst.media_player_new()
media = inst.media_new('track.opus')
player.set_media(media)
player.play()
```

And the volume process on windows is displayed like this

[image: app in volume mixer menu]

And like this on linux

[image]

Comment: which UI framework are you using? This is not libvlc related

Comment: None, it's just a python script that use python-vlc(https://pypi.org/project/python-vlc/) to play songs

Comment: Well, you might need to hook into the OS APIs (such as win32 for Windows) to set such a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works via instance. Try: set_user_agent(name, http)

```
vlc_instance = vlc.Instance()
vlc_instance.set_user_agent("Application Name", "HTTP/User/Agent")
```

See https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/vlc.Instance-class.html